# How to convert RGB PIL image to numpy array with 3 channels?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am loading image with the following code

```
image = PIL.Image.open(file_path)
image = np.array(image)
```

It works, but the size of array appears to be `(X, X, 4)`, i.e. it has 4 layers. I would like normal RGB layers. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

I found that just removing 4th channel is unsufficcient. The following code was required:

```
image = PIL.Image.open(file_path)
image.thumbnail(resample_size)
image = image.convert("RGB")
image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32) / 255
image = image[:, :, :3]
```

Why?

Comment: Just clip to three channels : `image[...,:3]`.

Comment: The fourth layer is the alpha (i.e. transparency) channel.  Are you sure you don't want that?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I am reading JPEGs, as far as I know they don't contain alpha.

Comment: When I do `np.asarray(my_pil_img).shape` it returns `(480, 640, 3)` on a 480x640 .png image without alpha. Is this something that has been "fixed" in a later version since this post?

Answer (score 42):

The fourth  layer is the transparency value for image formats that support transparency, like PNG.  If you remove the 4th value it'll be a correct RGB image without transparency.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
>>> import PIL.Image
>>> image = PIL.Image.open('../test.png')
>>> import numpy as np
>>> image = np.array(image)
>>> image.shape
(381, 538, 4)
>>> image[...,:3].shape
(381, 538, 3)
```

Comment: This changes shape `(64, 64, 4)` to `(22, 64, 4)`

Comment: Fixed the edit thanks to @Divakar's correct example.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by other answers, some images are saved with a 4th channel.
To load image with just `RGB` channels without using `numpy` at all:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('../test.png').convert('RGB')
```