# How to get color of all pixels in an area in python

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to write a program on linux that does something if the pixels in an area aren't all the same color, for example:

```py
if color not "255, 255, 255":
    #do something
```

this is what i have for one pixel:

```py
import time, pyautogui
time.clock()
image = pyautogui.screenshot()
color = image.getpixel((1006, 553))
print(time.clock())
print(color)
```

I know how to get the color of a pixel using `.getpixel()` but that only gets one pixel

Basically, how do i get the color of an area of pixels when i know all the pixels in that area are the same color.

Also, as quick as possible, like 0.5s or under.

Comment: Consider using a ranged `for` loop to go over all pixels in the area - if one or more doesn't match the previous pixel, the check fails.

Comment: @NickReed wouldn't that be really slow though?

Comment: Depends how big your image is. 0.5 seconds is a LOT of time for a program - it should be enough for any image of realistic size. Are you *certain* the area is all the same pixel, though, or is that what your code is trying to determine?

Comment: What libraries are you using? I'm sure there are many different ones who have a `.getpixel()` method. A runtime goal of 0.5s is meaningless if we don't know anything about your data!

Comment: @Fízli That would depend on the size of the area.

Comment: @Carcigenicate about 640x170 pixels

Comment: @Fízli So like 100k pixels. On my phone, a comparable operation takes 0.0112 seconds to process the data (timed using `timeit`, `n=1000`) That doesn't include the time needed to get the data though since that's highly dependant.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Cool! I'll try the `for` loop then.

Comment: Just use Numpy (`np.var`) to calculate the variance of any subimage. If it is zero, there is no variation in the colour.

Answer (score 0):

I keep recommending it, but the [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org) library is pretty great, and they have some really solid documentation and examples. I would recommend a combo of that and using numpy arrays directly. It is just a lot faster when working directly with pixels. 
You will have to convert the [PIL image to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955656/how-to-convert-rgb-pil-image-to-numpy-array-with-3-channels)...but this should work with that:

```
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

image = pyautogui.screenshot()
np_image = np.array(image)
```

You can slice the image:

```
red_slice = np_image[0:50, 0:50,0]
red_mask = red_slice == 200
```

This would give you the values for red in the upper right 50x50 pixel area. `red_mask` is an array of `True`/`False` values whether each red value in that area is equal to `200`. This can be repeated for the other channels as you see fit.