# "Unsupported number of image dimensions" while using image_utils from Transformers

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to follow this HuggingFace tutorial https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-vit

Using their "beans" dataset everything works, but if I use my own dataset with my own images, I'm hitting "Unsupported number of image dimensions". I'm wondering if anyone here would have pointers for how to debug this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2042949/883871373.py in <module>
----> 1 train_results = trainer.train()
      2 trainer.save_model()
      3 trainer.log_metrics("train", train_results.metrics)
      4 trainer.save_metrics("train", train_results.metrics)
      5 trainer.save_state()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1532             self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1533         )
-> 1534         return inner_training_loop(
   1535             args=args,
   1536             resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1754 
   1755             step = -1
-> 1756             for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
   1757 
   1758                 # Skip past any already trained steps if resuming training

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    626                 # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
...
--> 119         raise ValueError(f"Unsupported number of image dimensions: {image.ndim}")
    120 
    121     if image.shape[first_dim] in (1, 3):

ValueError: Unsupported number of image dimensions: 2
```

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/image_utils.py

I tried looking at the shape of my data and theirs and it's the same.

```
$ prepared_ds['train'][0:2]['pixel_values'].shape
torch.Size([2, 3, 224, 224])
```

I followed the stack trace and found that the error was in the `infer_channel_dimension_format` function, so I wrote this filth to find the problematic image:

```
from transformers.image_utils import infer_channel_dimension_format
try:
    for i, img in enumerate(prepared_ds["train"]):
        infer_channel_dimension_format(img["pixel_values"])
except ValueError as ve:
    print(i+1)
```

When I inspected that image, I saw that its not RGB like the others.

```
$ ds["train"][8]
{'image': <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=L size=390x540>,
 'image_file_path': '/data/alamy/img/00000/000001069.jpg',
 'labels': 0}
```

So the solution for me was to add a `convert('RGB')` to my transform:

```
def transform(example_batch):
    # Take a list of PIL images and turn them to pixel values
    inputs = feature_extractor([x.convert("RGB") for x in example_batch['image']], return_tensors='pt')

    # Don't forget to include the labels!
    inputs['labels'] = example_batch['labels']
    return inputs
```

I will try to find some time to come back here and clean this up with a fully reproducible example. (Sorry)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when following the Huggingface CLIPSeg zero-shot semantic segmentation tutorial. I was trying to provide it a single channel, numpy array of an IRB TIF image in the shape (500,500).

I turned the the three IRB channel into numpy arrays and stacked them with:

```
irb = np.dstack((i, r, b))
```

The shape was then (500,500,3) and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error today, after using the collate function, the above error was solved,

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    return {
        'pixel_values': torch.stack([x['pixel_values'] for x in batch]),
        'labels': torch.tensor([x['labels'] for x in batch])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error shown above. The problem was due to an extra dimension in the third axis of the image that had no information content. This is likely a transparency layer. If this is the same problem you're having you can determine it easily by doing the following:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(<your_image>).shape)
```

In my case image output shape was the following:
`(1016, 993, 4)`

The fourth channel is a transparency layer which isn't handled by the image processor. The fix is easy. Simply cut out the fourth transparency layer with the following:

```
image = PIL.Image.open(file_path)
image = np.array(image)
image = image[:, :, :3]
```

You can see why the fourth layer is there from this post:
[How to convert RGB PIL image to numpy array with 3 channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955656/how-to-convert-rgb-pil-image-to-numpy-array-with-3-channels)